# SF book set in a near-future England with bioengineered trees and birth control rings

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a book about 5 years ago that has really stuck with me, everything but the name and author. Hoping someone here will remember it from some details.

- Near future England.
- There are bioengineered trees to work on climate change.
- There are mandatory birth control laws or debates about those laws with religious or philosophical objections.
- There are some kind of birth control rings people wear on their fingers.
- An issue with a gene that lets people see through time.
- It's mostly about a husband and a wife.
- The wife didn't want the ring for some reason.
- Pretty sure it's from the last 20 years if not 10.

It's been driving me crazy! Any ideas?

Comment: Possibly one of Rysa Walker's Chronos Files series? I haven't read them but they definitely involved a gene that allowed you to use a ring to time travel.

Comment: The J. G. Ballard short story *The Voices of Time* concerns a gene that when activated enables to to see time i.e. you can look at rocks and see the millions of years since they were formed. Could this be what you are remembering?